# Realm for Android, how to sync server data to realm database?

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm trying to sync `City` list

```
public class City extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("clubs")
    private RealmList<Club> clubs;
}
```

that also contains clubs, and `Club` contains various other models. Is there a simple way I can make local Realm database identical to the response, like if the City is not returned in json, I need to remove it from Realm, otherwise update it. My current thoughts are to do two iterations, one to update and create new City instances, other to remove unneeded ones.

For example, updating a user info from server, when the user has read news only saved locally, is troublesome as is:

```
private void createOrUpdateUser(User updated) {
    User user = mRealm.where(User.class).equalTo("id", updated.getId()).findFirst();

    mRealm.beginTransaction();

    RealmList<RealmInt> removedNews;

    if (user != null) {
        removedNews = new RealmList<>();
        removedNews.addAll(user.getRemovedNews());
    } else {
        removedNews = new RealmList<>();
    }

    updated = mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(updated);
    updated.setRemovedNews(removedNews);

    mRealm.commitTransaction();
}
```

If I don't wrap relations to another `ArrayList`/`RealmList` and re-set it on the updated entry, then `copyToRealmOrUpdate` completely removes them and there's no way to get them back.

```
updated.setRemovedNews(user.getRemovedNews());
```

Has the same outcome, when `copyToRealmOrUpdate` is executed, the updated user has 0 read news. Same goes even when I replace `RealmInt` with `News` model thas has `@PrimaryKey`.

Retrofit2, Gson and Realm is used.

Comment: you can try android sync adapter

Comment: Is `updated` a standalone/unmanaged object?

Comment: Yes, the `updated` is unmanaged object. So far I'm just manually looping through array, fetching existing records and reattaching child records to them on update as I found a bug with copyToRealmOrUpdate? if an object has inner objects with the same primary key (club has master coach and another list of all coaches, they're of type `Coach` and `RealmList<Coach>`), I get a primary key violation exception, but if I go through and save them one by one and attach managed versions, it works fine.

Comment: I don't think there is a better way to do that than what you are doing in `createOrUpdateUser` :( I created an issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2288 to track this. Maybe something like `public <E extends RealmObject> E copyToRealmOrUpdate(E object, String... ignoredFields)` could be helpful in this case.